# Replacing certain letters in a string by every other letter in a list

Tags: python, string, list, split, character

I have two lists: one list of strings, another of single character strings:

```
basis = ['ssaa','asas']
sample = ['x','y','z']
```

I want my program to replace **every** 's' character in basis with **every** element in the sample list. So the result should look like:

```
result = ['xxaa','xyaa','xzaa','yxaa','yyaa','yzaa','zxaa','zyaa','zzaa','axax','axay','axaz'...]
```

so result contains all possible combinations.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Do you have any code you've written so far that you can post to get help with?

Comment: you're looking for a combination of `itertools.product` and `re.sub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
from itertools import product

basis = ['ssaa','asas']
sample = ['x','y','z']

results = []
for base in basis:
    for comb in map(list, product(sample, repeat=base.count('s'))):
        results.append(''.join(comb.pop(0) if l == 's' else l for l in base))
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain, product

basis = ['ssaa', 'asas']
sample = ['x', 'y', 'z']

result = list(chain(*[
    map(lambda c: ''.join(c),
        product(*[sample if b == 's' else b for b in bb])
    ) for bb in basis
]))
```

This piece of code can be reused (simplified) to generate all possible words during a Hangman game :)

```
from itertools import chain, product
import string

current = '_a_e' # game? fame? lame? ;)
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

words = map(
    lambda c: ''.join(c),
    product(*[letters if x == '_' else x for x in current])
)
```